# Woocommerce. Trying to obtain the id of product attribute terms

Tags: woocommerce

I have a product attribute set up of 'Properties'. Within the properties attribute I have the following terms:

- Multiple sizes
- Polyester
- 100% Cotton
  etc...

I have an acf field containing an image for each term, to display this on the front end I need to access the ID of the term (eg '100% Cotton has an ID of 44).

The attributes are looped on the product page as follows:

```
                global $product;

                $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

                if ( ! $attributes ) return;

                $out = '<div class="custom-attributes">';

                foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

                    if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) continue;


                    if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

                        $taxonomy = $attribute->get_name();
                        $taxonomy_id = $attribute->get_id();
                        $taxo_obj = $attribute->get_taxonomy_object();
                        $name = $taxo_obj->attribute_name;
                        $label = $taxo_obj->attribute_label;
                        $label_name = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                        $values = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

                        $out .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $taxonomy ) . ' single-attribute" style="margin-top: 20px;">';

                        $out .= '<div class="attribute-label '.$label.'" "style="margin-top: 20px;">Label: '.$label_name.' - '.$taxonomy_id.'</div><!-- attribute-label -->';

                        $out .= '<div class="attribute-values">';

                        $out .= 'Value: '.$values;

                        $out .= '</div><!-- attribute-values -->';

                        $out .= '</div><!-- ' . esc_attr( $taxonomy ) . ' single-attribute-->';

                    } else {
                        $taxonomy = $attribute->get_name();
                        $out .= '<div class="' . sanitize_title($taxonomy) . '-custom" style="margin-top: 20px;">';
                        $out .= '<div class="attribute-label-custom">' . $taxonomy . ': </div><!-- attribute-label-custom-->';
                        $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
                        $out .= '<div class="attribute-value-custom">' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '</div><!-- attribute-value-custom-->';
                        $out .= '</div><!-- ' . sanitize_title($taxonomy) . '-custom-->';
                    }
                }

                echo $out;
```

The following only returns the name of the terms selected:

```
$values = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
```

How do I get it to return their IDs too?

Comment: You should use ` $attribute->get_terms()` to get terms objects array then you can loop through it and get the ID, name, slug, etc

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I'm there with it, will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so following Vijays steer, approached it from the direction utilising `$attribute->get_terms()`, and here's my working code.

I'm not a programmer and find the nested foreach a little awkward, so I'm to optimisations and alternate approaches.

```
global $product;

$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->is_taxonomy()) {
        $taxonomy = $attribute->get_terms();

        $first = true;
        foreach ($taxonomy as $valueSet) {

            if ($first) {
                $taxonomy_name = wc_attribute_label($valueSet->taxonomy);
                echo '<h5>'.$taxonomy_name.'</h5>';
                $first = false;
            }

            $image = get_field('image', $valueSet->taxonomy.'_'.$valueSet->term_id);
            if ($image) {
              echo '<img src="'. $image['url'] .'" alt="'.$valueSet->name.'">';
            }
            echo '<p>'.$valueSet->name.'</p>';
        }
    }
    if (!$attribute->is_taxonomy()) {

        $taxonomy_name = $attribute->get_name();
        echo '<h5>'.$taxonomy_name.'</h5>';
        $value_string = implode(', ', $attribute->get_options());
        echo '<p>' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

But this gets me the global attributes for the product with access to the ACF fields I needed, plus loops the custom attributes that are not taxonomies.